# Working for Stack Exchange, who and how?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team

I would like to know, how can a user become a Stack Exchange employee? What if I've asked a lot of questions and earned good badges and a lot of points? How is it possible? I've read Stack Exchange employs some users to post questions and answer answers. Is this true? What about other jobs with Stack Exchange, what are they, and how could it be possible to get them?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't employ anybody who's sole and primary job is to post or answer questions. Well, outside of meta sites where we solicit feedback or respond to bug reports or questions like yours. But even then, it's not a core part of anyone's job.

We're not that different from other tech companies out there. We have [job openings](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here), people apply to them, and some get hired. Existing site participation is nice to see, but it's not a requirement for or a guarantee of getting hired.